# Disable ESC key

Tags: keymap, xmodmap

the ESC key on my computer is bad and causes the computer to misbehave. i tried disabling by using

> xmodmap -e 'keycode 9='

But resulted in errors

> xmodmap:  commandline:1:  bad keycode input line
>   xmodmap:  1 error encountered, aborting.

please help.

Comment: You could use `dconf-editor` - have you tried that? Link for reference, it shows how to swap esc key with caps lock, but it should still be viable in the question to what you are trying to accomplish: [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363346/how-to-permanently-switch-caps-lock-and-esc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This eventually worked for me. instead of giving a blank assignment i gave it `NoSymbol`

> xmodmap -e 'keycode 9=NoSymbol'